# What are the tools, programming languages and development processes of AAA games?

Tags: tools, methodology

Only thing I am able to find about "big" games like ac, hl, bf, cod is engine used to run the game. But I am interested in what software development methodology, programming and scripting languages were used. As well as tools for creating models, music, animations and other media. Further, were the team team organisations and so on for a certain game (or game series). 
Is this information even available to the public?

Comment: This entirely depends on the game. Sometimes that information is available via talks, papers, etc. So the answer is: **Sometimes, it depends**. However, this question isn't appropriate for this site, as it's overly broad and isn't actually helpful.

Comment: This information would generally be available if (1) it was intentionally divulged, (2) it was leaked, or (3) it can be discerned by playing the game.

Comment: stephelton, number 3 is very interesting. Its true, that one can recognize games running on Unreal or Source engine. But recognizing used programming language just by looking? :-D 

Byte56, it may not be helpful for everyone, but few people might be interested in this topic. It is same as listening to good music and asking yourself, what instruments they have used. And knowing what tools are used I can learn to play and create good music too ;-)

Comment: I am interested, because I want to know things. I would not run and learn all of them.
Anyway, thanks for your comments :-)

Comment: @Pan.student Despite the question being closed, you should find this interesting:  http://isaaclean.com/starting-game-development/what-its-like-being-an-ea-engineer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

many times the engine will determine the language (or possible set of languages) UDK uses Unreal script with the option of C++ DLL binding. Uninty uses either Java, or Mono with the option of their own scripting language. XNA uses C#. what this amounts to is if you are trying to figure out what language, or engine to use it should be determined based on more then just what others have done. (see my answer here for more on that [When should I decide what language and platforms I will use for a project?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/25955/when-should-i-decide-what-language-and-platforms-i-will-use-for-a-project/25961#25961) )

The software tools used will depend on familiarity with the product, capabilities of the product, and the licensing. the specific tool used for GameX is not the point its the artistic direction of the game, and that is a design concern.

For constructing the teams this is rather open ended, and vary diverse. it could be anywhere from a group of friends who like games, and want to get together, and make one. It could be a group who went to a school for game development, and want to work together. or it could just be that a person undertakes the project to start with, and then puts a posting on craigslist for help. how you chose to build your team is up to you.

the overall answer is simply "don't be a ape taught to make something good. be an individual who has an idea, and goes for it"